# Notepad++ Append Line1 Text to the end of Line2, Line3 to Line4, Line5 to Line 6, and so on

Tags: string, replace, command, notepad++, line

I have been Googling my way through manipulating a configuration file to migrate data to another operating system using Notepad++. I have been successful thus far with the plethora of examples and help online with Notepad++. However, I've hit a road block that I'm not able to overcome and require assistance. Here's my plight...

I have a config file of objects, but they are presented in the wrong order for building the command set I need to make this useable. All of the data is presented in an incorrect order. Line 1 should be appended to the end of Line 2, Line 3 should be appended to the end of Line 4, Line 5 should be appended to the end of Line 6, and so on...

```
static "PMDC1-2019"
set device-group plymouth_meeting address-group "DNS Servers"
static "PMDC2-2019"
set device-group plymouth_meeting address-group "DNS Servers"
static "ExtonDC-2019"
set device-group plymouth_meeting address-group "DNS Servers"
static "wellcall-lodidc"
set device-group plymouth_meeting address-group "DNS Servers"
```

The end result should be as follows:

```
set device-group plymouth_meeting address-group "DNS Servers" static "PMDC1-2019"
set device-group plymouth_meeting address-group "DNS Servers" static "PMDC2-2019"
set device-group plymouth_meeting address-group "DNS Servers" static "ExtonDC-2019"
set device-group plymouth_meeting address-group "DNS Servers" static "wellcall-lodidc"
```

All suggestions and assistance are welcome and appreciated! Thank you.

I've tried to piece together found extended and regex examples without luck. I tried the option and parenthesis method to capture the data and insert it, but failed with that as well. I guess my inexperience with these variables and programming logic are getting the best of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)\R(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$2 $1`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(.+)        # group 1, 1 or more any character
\R          # any kind of linebreak
(.+)        # group 2, 1 or more any character
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]